# how pass variables in api calll python?

Tags: python, json

i have a simple api call that should return me the news based on stock tickers i pass in the get request. But I would like to pass the data array to the API call. How do I pass all the values in the data list to the API call request?

```
def main():

    data = ["AAPL", "SQ", "PLTR"]
    // API call which I would like to pass values in data 
response = requests.get("https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1tickers=data&items=50&date=last7days&token=myapikey")
```

Comment: You mean like the [quickstart](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) shows in one of the first few examples?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean how to get input from the user? or how to pass array to the api url?

Comment: how to pass aray to the api url

Comment: first you would have to check documentation for this API - to see how it can get it - in URL, in POST as normal data or JSON.

Comment: if API expects it in URL then you can  use `get(""https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1", params={...})`

Comment: this is a sample api call https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers=FB,AAPl&items=50&token=apikey  , just need to pass data array to tickers params

Comment: it is simple string formattiong - or use arguments in `requests` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `params` in `requests` to use arguments in url

```
import requests

data = ["AAPL", "SQ", "PLTR"]
data_str = ",".join(data)

url = "https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1"

payload = {
    "tickers": data_str,
    "items": 50,
    "date": "last7days",
    "token": "myapikey",
}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

Eventually you can use string formatting with `{}` and `.format(data_str)`

```
data_str = ",".join(data)

url = "https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers={}&items=50&date=last7days&token=myapikey".format(data_str)
```

or `f-string` with `{data_str}`

```
data_str = ",".join(data)

url = f"https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers={data_str}&items=50&date=last7days&token=myapikey"
```